# How can I extract keyframe and p-frame from stream with single command using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to extract two kind of frames from a tv stream using ffmpeg at the same time.

My question is how can I get two two **I** and **P** frames using one single command?

e.g : command to get all keyframes in ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -i http://my-tv-stream.m3u8 -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i http://my-tv-stream.m3u8 -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,I)+eq(pict_type\,P)'" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

---

To output the frame types separately, use

```
ffmpeg -i http://my-tv-stream.m3u8 -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 I-thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
       -vf "select='eq(pict_type\,P)" -vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 P-thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

Comment: I forgot to ask about this issue as well. how can I indicate the type of output images by the type of frames then?

Comment: Edited into answer.